# MS Access. Names in forms instead of ID's

Tags: database, forms

i have two tables

```
student(studentid, name, class)
Course (courseID, CourseName, CreditHours)
```

these tables have many to many relation ship so i created a third table

```
student_course(studentID,CourseID)
```

Now i have designed the forms in ms access through which user enters data in **`student and course tables`**

But i want to design a from through which user can assign courses to students which means user
have to enter data in **`student_course`** table.

but i want to design a form though which users can see and enter the student name and course name insted of `ID's` at `backend ID` should store in `student_course` table,

Can anyone help me in this matter.

Comment: You can solve this in 2 ways. A dropdownlist , with ID as datafield and Name as Display Field. Or, a text-box with a autocomplete from the database

Comment: How can i show dropdown list with ID as datafield and Name as Display fields on ms access form.
can you please guide me?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a combo box .. try to insert a combo box on the form using the wizard and it should walk you through the steps in showing the course name in the front end and saving the course id in the back end database ...